# data seems to have been wiped after resizing partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, data-recovery

I have a Windows laptop that I created an Ubuntu 16.04 partition on and have been using for the last few months. It then ran out of space so I used software called AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition to resize the partition, after which I have found my Ubuntu partition going onto the grub screen rather than the normal login screen.

I have tried seeing the content of my partitions from grub using ls (hd.. but I just get the message "Unknown filesystem". I have found software that is able to recover lost files after partition resizing for Windows, but have no idea how I would do it for my Ubuntu partition.

None of the other questions that have been posted seem to apply to me hence me posting a new question. I can't think of what extra details to post at the moment but please let me know if you have any ideas.

If someone can help me try to recover the files from that partition I would be forever grateful as there are lots of precious files on there.
Thanks

**EDIT**: I've used testdisk and have obtained a logfile. I have posted the extract that I think is most relevant, though as I am not probably the best of judge of this, have included a link to the full logfile [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzXU750293dQODhsOFZpRThRV3M/view?usp=sharing).

I have a feeling that I'm screwed but if anyone can confirm this for me or help further that would be great. Also, if it is the case that I have wiped all of my data, how can I safely reinstall Ubuntu and have my partitions how they should be again?

**Logfile**:

```
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error

ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented

     MS Data                 19163521  245665984  226502464
     NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=4096, 115 GB / 108 GiB
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented

     MS Data                245659647  490751998  245092352
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 125 GB / 116 GiB
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented


dir_partition inode=5
     MS Data                245665984  472168447  226502464 [LENOVO]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 115 GB / 108 GiB
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 22-May-2017 06:12 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 22-May-2017 06:12 ..
      36 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 11-Jan-2017 17:36 $RECYCLE.BIN
      37 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 26-Sep-2016 00:12 Drivers
    2656 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 11-Jan-2017 17:19 System Volume Information

dir_partition inode=37
     MS Data                245665984  472168447  226502464 [LENOVO]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 115 GB / 108 GiB
Directory /Drivers
      37 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 26-Sep-2016 00:12 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 22-May-2017 06:12 ..
      38 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:59 Audio
      48 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:58 Bluetooth
      74 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:58 Camera
      78 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 23:01 CardReader
      86 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:55 Chipset
      87 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:56 IRST
      88 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:59 LAN
     127 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:49 LenovoUtility
     135 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:56 MEI
     136 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 23:02 OneKey_Recovery
     199 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:59 Touchpad
     201 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:56 VGA
     268 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 23:00 WLAN
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 22-May-2017 06:12 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 22-May-2017 06:12 ..
      36 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 11-Jan-2017 17:36 $RECYCLE.BIN
      37 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 26-Sep-2016 00:12 Drivers
    2656 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 11-Jan-2017 17:19 System Volume Information
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented

     MS Data                450363393  474216448   23853056
     NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=4096, 12 GB / 11 GiB
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented

     MS Data                470120449  472168448    2048000
     NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented


dir_partition inode=5
     MS Data                472168448  474216447    2048000 [WINRE_DRV]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 ..
      36 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:53 $RECYCLE.BIN
      37 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:39 Recovery
      42 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 System Volume Information

dir_partition inode=37
     MS Data                472168448  474216447    2048000 [WINRE_DRV]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
Directory /Recovery
      37 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:39 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 ..
      38 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 WindowsRE
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Janntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00f2c9ee  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 59894  usa_count: 60929: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xf2c9ee)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00f2c9ee  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 59894  usa_count: 60929: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0xf2c9ee)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
-2017 08:13 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 ..
      36 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:53 $RECYCLE.BIN
      37 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 22:39 Recovery
      42 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 System Volume Information
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented

     MS Data                473821395  473827568       6174
     NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=512, 3161 KB / 3087 KiB
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented


dir_partition inode=5
     MS Data                473827568  473833741       6174 [Boot]
     NTFS, blocksize=512, 3161 KB / 3087 KiB
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 15-Feb-2005 21:33 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 15-Feb-2005 21:33 ..
      27 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 15-Feb-2005 21:33 System Volume Information
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented

     MS Data                474216447  476264446    2048000
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
ntfs_device_testdisk_io_ioctl() unimplemented


dir_partition inode=5
     MS Data                474216448  498069503   23853056 [LENOVO_PART]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 12 GB / 11 GiB
Directory /
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 20-May-2017 16:08 .
       5 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 20-May-2017 16:08 ..
     659 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 26-Sep-2016 00:13 OKRBackup
     675 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 12-Jan-2017 08:13 System Volume Information
      36 dr-xr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 23:02 onekey


dir_partition inode=0
     EFI System             498069504  500117503    2048000 [EFI System Partition] [LRS_ESP]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=498077696
Directory /
       3 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0    395268  9-Jul-2015 06:30 BOOTMGR
     100 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0   1152864  9-Jul-2015 06:07 BOOTMGR.EFI
     382 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0       105 13-Sep-2015 18:12 Version.txt
     383 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 BG-BG
     403 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 Boot
    5690 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 CS-CZ
    5710 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DA-DK
    5730 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DE-DE
    5751 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EFI
   10753 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EL-GR
   10774 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-GB
   10794 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-US
   10814 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-ES
   10834 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-MX
   10854 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ET-EE
   10874 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FI-FI
   10894 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-CA
   10915 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-FR
   10936 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HR-HR
   10956 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HU-HU
   10977 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 IT-IT
   10997 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 JA-JP
   11015 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 KO-KR
   11033 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LT-LT
   11053 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LV-LV
   11073 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NB-NO
   11093 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NL-NL
   11114 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PL-PL
   11134 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-BR
   11154 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-PT
   11174 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RO-RO
   11194 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RU-RU
   11214 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SK-SK
   11234 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SL-SI
   11254 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SOURCES
  133871 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 sr-latn-rs
  133891 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SV-SE
  133911 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 TR-TR
  133931 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 UK-UA
  133951 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-CN
  133968 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-HK
  133985 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-TW
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59583.TMP
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59589.TMP

dir_partition inode=5690
     EFI System             498069504  500117503    2048000 [EFI System Partition] [LRS_ESP]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
FAT: cluster=5690(0x163a), pos=498123200
Directory /CS-CZ
    5690 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:54 .
       0 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:54 ..
    5691 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0     76640  9-Jul-2015 06:45 bootmgr.efi.mui
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=498077696
Directory /
       3 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0    395268  9-Jul-2015 06:30 BOOTMGR
     100 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0   1152864  9-Jul-2015 06:07 BOOTMGR.EFI
     382 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0       105 13-Sep-2015 18:12 Version.txt
     383 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 BG-BG
     403 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 Boot
    5690 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 CS-CZ
    5710 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DA-DK
    5730 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DE-DE
    5751 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EFI
   10753 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EL-GR
   10774 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-GB
   10794 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-US
   10814 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-ES
   10834 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-MX
   10854 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ET-EE
   10874 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FI-FI
   10894 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-CA
   10915 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-FR
   10936 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HR-HR
   10956 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HU-HU
   10977 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 IT-IT
   10997 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 JA-JP
   11015 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 KO-KR
   11033 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LT-LT
   11053 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LV-LV
   11073 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NB-NO
   11093 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NL-NL
   11114 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PL-PL
   11134 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-BR
   11154 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-PT
   11174 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RO-RO
   11194 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RU-RU
   11214 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SK-SK
   11234 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SL-SI
   11254 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SOURCES
  133871 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 sr-latn-rs
  133891 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SV-SE
  133911 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 TR-TR
  133931 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 UK-UA
  133951 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-CN
  133968 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-HK
  133985 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-TW
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59583.TMP
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59589.TMP

dir_partition inode=5710
     EFI System             498069504  500117503    2048000 [EFI System Partition] [LRS_ESP]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
FAT: cluster=5710(0x164e), pos=498123360
Directory /DA-DK
    5710 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:54 .
       0 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:54 ..
    5711 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0     76128  9-Jul-2015 06:45 bootmgr.efi.mui
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=498077696
Directory /
       3 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0    395268  9-Jul-2015 06:30 BOOTMGR
     100 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0   1152864  9-Jul-2015 06:07 BOOTMGR.EFI
     382 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0       105 13-Sep-2015 18:12 Version.txt
     383 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 BG-BG
     403 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 Boot
    5690 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 CS-CZ
    5710 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DA-DK
    5730 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DE-DE
    5751 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EFI
   10753 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EL-GR
   10774 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-GB
   10794 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-US
   10814 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-ES
   10834 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-MX
   10854 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ET-EE
   10874 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FI-FI
   10894 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-CA
   10915 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-FR
   10936 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HR-HR
   10956 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HU-HU
   10977 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 IT-IT
   10997 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 JA-JP
   11015 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 KO-KR
   11033 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LT-LT
   11053 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LV-LV
   11073 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NB-NO
   11093 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NL-NL
   11114 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PL-PL
   11134 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-BR
   11154 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-PT
   11174 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RO-RO
   11194 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RU-RU
   11214 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SK-SK
   11234 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SL-SI
   11254 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SOURCES
  133871 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 sr-latn-rs
  133891 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SV-SE
  133911 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 TR-TR
  133931 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 UK-UA
  133951 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-CN
  133968 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-HK
  133985 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-TW
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59583.TMP
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59589.TMP

dir_partition inode=10854
     EFI System             498069504  500117503    2048000 [EFI System Partition] [LRS_ESP]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
FAT: cluster=10854(0x2a66), pos=498164512
Directory /ET-EE
   10854 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:54 .
       0 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:54 ..
   10855 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0     75104  9-Jul-2015 06:45 bootmgr.efi.mui
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=498077696
Directory /
       3 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0    395268  9-Jul-2015 06:30 BOOTMGR
     100 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0   1152864  9-Jul-2015 06:07 BOOTMGR.EFI
     382 -rwxr-xr-x     0      0       105 13-Sep-2015 18:12 Version.txt
     383 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 BG-BG
     403 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 Boot
    5690 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 CS-CZ
    5710 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DA-DK
    5730 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 DE-DE
    5751 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EFI
   10753 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EL-GR
   10774 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-GB
   10794 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 EN-US
   10814 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-ES
   10834 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ES-MX
   10854 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ET-EE
   10874 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FI-FI
   10894 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-CA
   10915 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 FR-FR
   10936 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HR-HR
   10956 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 HU-HU
   10977 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 IT-IT
   10997 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 JA-JP
   11015 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 KO-KR
   11033 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LT-LT
   11053 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 LV-LV
   11073 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NB-NO
   11093 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 NL-NL
   11114 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PL-PL
   11134 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-BR
   11154 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 PT-PT
   11174 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RO-RO
   11194 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 RU-RU
   11214 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SK-SK
   11234 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SL-SI
   11254 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SOURCES
  133871 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 sr-latn-rs
  133891 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 SV-SE
  133911 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 TR-TR
  133931 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 UK-UA
  133951 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-CN
  133968 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-HK
  133985 drwxr-xr-x     0      0         0 25-Sep-2016 15:25 ZH-TW
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59583.TMP
X   2930 drwxr-xr-x     0      0      4096 25-Sep-2016 16:02 _SI59589.TMP


dir_partition inode=0
     MS Data                498069510  500117509    2048000 [NO NAME]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 1048 MB / 1000 MiB
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=498077702
FAT: cluster=771(0x303), pos=498083854
FAT: cluster=1540(0x604), pos=498090006
FAT: cluster=2309(0x905), pos=498096158
FAT: cluster=3078(0xc06), pos=498102310
FAT: cluster=3847(0xf07), pos=498108462
FAT: cluster=4616(0x1208), pos=498114614
FAT: cluster=5385(0x1509), pos=498120766
FAT: cluster=6154(0x180a), pos=498126918
FAT: cluster=6923(0x1b0b), pos=498133070
FAT: cluster=7692(0x1e0c), pos=498139222
FAT: cluster=8461(0x210d), pos=498145374
FAT: cluster=9230(0x240e), pos=498151526
FAT: cluster=9999(0x270f), pos=498157678
FAT: cluster=10768(0x2a10), pos=498163830
FAT: cluster=11537(0x2d11), pos=498169982
FAT: cluster=12306(0x3012), pos=498176134
FAT: cluster=13075(0x3313), pos=498182286
FAT: cluster=13844(0x3614), pos=498188438
FAT: cluster=14613(0x3915), pos=498194590
FAT: cluster=15382(0x3c16), pos=498200742
FAT: cluster=16151(0x3f17), pos=498206894
FAT: cluster=16920(0x4218), pos=498213046
FAT: cluster=17689(0x4519), pos=498219198
FAT: cluster=18458(0x481a), pos=498225350
FAT: cluster=19227(0x4b1b), pos=498231502
FAT: cluster=19996(0x4e1c), pos=498237654
FAT: cluster=20765(0x511d), pos=498243806
FAT: cluster=21534(0x541e), pos=498249958
FAT: cluster=22303(0x571f), pos=498256110
FAT: cluster=23072(0x5a20), pos=498262262
FAT: cluster=23841(0x5d21), pos=498268414
FAT: cluster=24610(0x6022), pos=498274566
FAT: cluster=25379(0x6323), pos=498280718
FAT: cluster=26148(0x6624), pos=498286870
FAT: cluster=26917(0x6925), pos=498293022
FAT: cluster=27686(0x6c26), pos=498299174
FAT: cluster=28455(0x6f27), pos=498305326
FAT: cluster=29224(0x7228), pos=498311478
FAT: cluster=29993(0x7529), pos=498317630
FAT: cluster=30762(0x782a), pos=498323782
FAT: cluster=31531(0x7b2b), pos=498329934
FAT: cluster=32300(0x7e2c), pos=498336086
FAT: cluster=33069(0x812d), pos=498342238
FAT: cluster=33838(0x842e), pos=498348390
FAT: cluster=34607(0x872f), pos=498354542
FAT: cluster=35376(0x8a30), pos=498360694
FAT: cluster=36145(0x8d31), pos=498366846
FAT: cluster=36914(0x9032), pos=498372998
FAT: cluster=37683(0x9333), pos=498379150
FAT: cluster=38452(0x9634), pos=498385302
FAT: cluster=39221(0x9935), pos=498391454
FAT: cluster=39990(0x9c36), pos=498397606
FAT: cluster=40759(0x9f37), pos=498403758
FAT: cluster=41528(0xa238), pos=498409910
FAT: cluster=42297(0xa539), pos=498416062
FAT: cluster=43066(0xa83a), pos=498422214
FAT: cluster=43835(0xab3b), pos=498428366
FAT: cluster=44604(0xae3c), pos=498434518
FAT: cluster=45373(0xb13d), pos=498440670
FAT: cluster=46142(0xb43e), pos=498446822
FAT: cluster=46911(0xb73f), pos=498452974
FAT: cluster=47680(0xba40), pos=498459126
FAT: cluster=48449(0xbd41), pos=498465278
FAT: cluster=49218(0xc042), pos=498471430
FAT: cluster=49987(0xc343), pos=498477582
FAT: cluster=50756(0xc644), pos=498483734
FAT: cluster=51525(0xc945), pos=498489886
FAT: cluster=52294(0xcc46), pos=498496038
FAT: cluster=53063(0xcf47), pos=498502190
FAT: cluster=53832(0xd248), pos=498508342
FAT: cluster=54601(0xd549), pos=498514494
FAT: cluster=55370(0xd84a), pos=498520646
FAT: cluster=56139(0xdb4b), pos=498526798
FAT: cluster=56908(0xde4c), pos=498532950
FAT: cluster=57677(0xe14d), pos=498539102
FAT: cluster=58446(0xe44e), pos=498545254
FAT: cluster=59215(0xe74f), pos=498551406
FAT: cluster=59984(0xea50), pos=498557558
FAT: cluster=60753(0xed51), pos=498563710
FAT: cluster=61522(0xf052), pos=498569862
FAT: cluster=62291(0xf353), pos=498576014
FAT: cluster=63060(0xf654), pos=498582166
FAT: cluster=63829(0xf955), pos=498588318
FAT: cluster=64598(0xfc56), pos=498594470
FAT: cluster=65367(0xff57), pos=498600622
FAT: cluster=66136(0x10258), pos=498606774
FAT: cluster=66905(0x10559), pos=498612926
FAT: cluster=67674(0x1085a), pos=498619078
FAT: cluster=68443(0x10b5b), pos=498625230
FAT: cluster=69212(0x10e5c), pos=498631382
FAT: cluster=69981(0x1115d), pos=498637534
FAT: cluster=70750(0x1145e), pos=498643686
FAT: cluster=71519(0x1175f), pos=498649838
FAT: cluster=72288(0x11a60), pos=498655990
FAT: cluster=73057(0x11d61), pos=498662142
FAT: cluster=73826(0x12062), pos=498668294
FAT: cluster=74595(0x12363), pos=498674446
FAT: cluster=75364(0x12664), pos=498680598
FAT: cluster=76133(0x12965), pos=498686750
FAT: cluster=76902(0x12c66), pos=498692902
FAT: cluster=77671(0x12f67), pos=498699054
FAT: cluster=78440(0x13268), pos=498705206
FAT: cluster=79209(0x13569), pos=498711358
FAT: cluster=79978(0x1386a), pos=498717510
FAT: cluster=80747(0x13b6b), pos=498723662
FAT: cluster=81516(0x13e6c), pos=498729814
FAT: cluster=82285(0x1416d), pos=498735966
FAT: cluster=83054(0x1446e), pos=498742118
FAT: cluster=83823(0x1476f), pos=498748270
FAT: cluster=84592(0x14a70), pos=498754422
FAT: cluster=85361(0x14d71), pos=498760574
FAT: cluster=86130(0x15072), pos=498766726
FAT: cluster=86899(0x15373), pos=498772878
FAT: cluster=87668(0x15674), pos=498779030
FAT: cluster=88437(0x15975), pos=498785182
FAT: cluster=89206(0x15c76), pos=498791334
FAT: cluster=89975(0x15f77), pos=498797486
FAT: cluster=90744(0x16278), pntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
```

Comment: According to http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html, the Aomei tool you used isn't even capable of resizing Linux ext* partitions. Maybe it just moved the partition borders without caring about the contained file system... And what do you mean by "I have found my Ubuntu partition going onto the grub screen rather than the normal login screen." ?

Comment: This situation sounds dire - one should never mess about with partitions without solid backups - but you could try booting the laptop with an Ubuntu live USB and see if you can mount the partition there.  If you can, you will be able to copy your files off to an external device, and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Re-install and restore a backup. Everyone you asked about how to resize a partition will tell you to make a backup. If you do not have one... Use a live dvd session and see if the disk you can mount are your Linux system and then make a backup.

Comment: Always use Windows Disk Management app to resize NTFS partitions, and gparted for Linux partitions/swap. You can try running `testdisk` to see if it can recover some of your files. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step. Otherwise, I think that your data is lost. Sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question to report the scan results of Testdisk.

Comment: Thank you all for your help so far, I have posted the logfile from Testdisk. Any advice is greatly appreciated.